# ESP32-S2 download BMP file from url

Tags: esp32

i'm using ESP32-S2 with  sd card SPI.
I'm usind SD.h library
Wifi connection
and i need to dowload a BMP form url http://example.com/test.bmp ( or in future generic binary file ) and store in SD Card.
I'm able to connect but not to save file streaming coming from url

```
void downloadImage(){
  // Connect to external web server
Serial.println("Checking if image available");


String imageName="bottone.bmp";
String fwVersionURL = FWURL + imageName;

client.begin(fwVersionURL);
// Get file, just to check if each reachable
int resp = client.GET();
Serial.print("Response: ");
Serial.println(resp);
// If file is reachable, start downloading
if(resp == 200){
  // get length of document (is -1 when Server sends no Content-Length header)
  totImageLength = client.getSize();
  // transfer to local variable
  int len = totImageLength;
  
  Serial.printf("FW Size: %u\n",totImageLength);
  // create buffer for read
  uint8_t buff[totImageLength] = { 0 };
  // get tcp stream
  WiFiClient * stream = client.getStreamPtr();
  // read all data from server
  Serial.println("Updating firmware...");
  while(client.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
       // get available data size
       size_t size = stream->available();
       if(size) {
          // read up to 128 byte
          int c = stream->readBytes(buff, ((size > sizeof(buff)) ? sizeof(buff) : size));
          // pass to function
        
       }
       delay(1);
  }
  File remoteImg = SD.open("/"+imageName, FILE_WRITE);
  remoteImg.write(buff, totImageLength);
  remoteImg.close();
  

}else{
  Serial.println("Cannot download file.");
}
client.end();
```

}

Comment: just copy the bytes from socket to file

Comment: Can you tell me, in my code how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: here I have something similar https://github.com/JAndrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/864383dcae0e3b6ec293592197b2da463b2a791a/examples/Advanced/OTASketchDownload_SD/OTASketchDownload_SD.ino#L86

Answer (score 0):

One can download a file using the WifiClient library for ESP32 microcontrollers using the code snippet below

```cpp
bool M_WIFI_CLASS::downloadFileHttpGet(String filename, String httpAddr, uint8_t sendTo){
  String dataStr = "";

  if ( LittleFS.exists(filename) ){
    dataStr = "DW WIFI: File requested already exists. ";
    this->interface->sendBLEstring( dataStr,  sendTo );  
    return false;
  }

 if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    this->start(10000, 5); // TTL , n attempts 
  }
  
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ){
    if (this->errMsgShown == false){
      this->errMsgShown = true;
      this->mserial->printStrln("WIFI DW GET: unable to connect to WIFI.");
      this->interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_RED;
      this->interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  File DW_File = LittleFS.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  if ( !DW_File ){
    if (this->errMsgShown == false){
      this->errMsgShown = true;
      this->mserial->printStrln("WIFI DW GET: error creating  file");
      this->interface->onBoardLED->led[0] = interface->onBoardLED->LED_RED;
      this->interface->onBoardLED->statusLED(100, 1);
    }
    return false;
  }
    HTTPClient http;
    http.setFollowRedirects(HTTPC_FORCE_FOLLOW_REDIRECTS);
    // configure server and url
    http.begin(httpAddr);
    // start connection and send HTTP header
    int httpCode = http.GET();
    if(httpCode < 1) {
      dataStr = "HTTP GET failed with error code " + String(http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str()) + " \n";
      this->interface->sendBLEstring( dataStr,  sendTo );  
      return false;
    }

    if(httpCode != HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      dataStr = "Server returned " + String(httpCode) + " error code\n";
      this->interface->sendBLEstring( dataStr,  sendTo );  
      return false;
    }

    // get length of document (is -1 when Server sends no Content-Length header)
    int len = http.getSize();

    // create buffer for read
    uint8_t buff[128] = { 0 };

    // get tcp stream
    WiFiClient * stream = http.getStreamPtr();

    // read all data from server
    while(http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
        // get available data size
        size_t size = stream->available();

        if(size) {
            // read up to 128 byte
            int c = stream->readBytes(buff, ((size > sizeof(buff)) ? sizeof(buff) : size));

            DW_File.write(buff,c);
            if(len > 0) {
                len -= c;
            }
        }
        delay(1);
  }

  DW_File.close();

  http.end();
  return true;

}
```